# what is good way to generate a "symmetric ladder" or "adjacent" matrix using tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, matrix

(Updated I forget to say the input is batched) Given a bool array, e.g. `[[false, false, false, true, false, false, true, false, false], [false, true, false, false, false, false, true, false, false]]`, which "true" define the boundary of the separate sequence. I want to generate an adjacent matrix denoting the different group separated by the boundary. What is a good way to generate following "symmetric ladder" matrix using Tensorflow?

```
    [[
    [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
    [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
    [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
    [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
    ]
    [
    [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
    [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
    [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
    [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
    [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
    [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
    [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
    ]]
```

**Update Jun 15 2018:** 
Actually, I just have some progress on this problem, if I can convert the input senqence from [false, false, false, true, false, false, true, false, false] to [1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3], I can get some result using following Tensorflow code. But I am not sure is there a vector operation can convert [false, false, false, true, false, false, true, false, false] to [1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3]?

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()

x = tf.constant([1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3], shape=(9, 1), dtype=tf.int32)
y = tf.squeeze(tf.cast(tf.equal(tf.expand_dims(x, 1), x), tf.int32))
print(sess.run(y))
[[1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]]
```

**Update finally:**
I inspired a lot from @Willem Van Onsem.
For batched version can be solved by modifying a little from @Willem Van Onsem solution.

```
import tensorflow as tf
b = tf.constant([[False, False, False, True, False, False, True, False, False], [False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]], shape=(2, 9, 1), dtype=tf.int32)
x = (1 + tf.cumsum(tf.cast(b, tf.int32), axis=1))  * (1-b)
x = tf.cast(tf.equal(x, tf.transpose(x, perm=[0,2,1])),tf.int32) - tf.transpose(b, perm=[0,2,1])*b


with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(sess.run(x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I am not sure is there a vector operation can convert `[False, False, False, True, False, False, True, False, False]` to `[1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3]`

There is, consider the following example:

```
b = tf.constant([False, False, False, True, False, False, True, False, False], shape=(9,), dtype=tf.int32)
```

then we can use [**`tf.cumsum(..)`**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cumsum) to generate:

```
>>> print(sess.run(1+tf.cumsum(b)))
[1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3]
```

If we then multiply the values with the opposite of `b`, we get:

```
>>> print(sess.run((1+tf.cumsum(b))*(1-b)))
[1 1 1 0 2 2 0 3 3]
```

So we can store this expression in a variable, for example `x`:

```
x = (1+tf.cumsum(b))*(1-b)
```

> I want to generate an adjacent matrix denoting the different group separated by the boundary. What is a good way to generate following "symmetric ladder" matrix using Tensorflow?

If we follow your approach, we only have to remove the points where both lists are `0` at the same time. We can do this with:

```
tf.cast(tf.equal(x, tf.transpose(x)),tf.int32) - tf.transpose(b)*b
```

So here we use your approach, where we basically broadcast `x`, and the transpose of `x`, and check for elementwise equality, and we subtract the element-wise multiplication of `b` from, it. This then yields:

```
>>> print(sess.run(tf.cast(tf.equal(x, tf.transpose(x)),tf.int32) - tf.transpose(b)*b))
[[1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]]
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I wonder is that possible the input it not single vector? E.g. b = tf.constant([[False, False, False, True, False, False, True, False, False], [False, False, False, True, False, False, True, False, False]], shape=(9,2), dtype=tf.int32)

Comment: @Hypnoz: what should be the output then? A 4d tensor?

Comment: Actually I think it is 3d tensor. because previous output is 2d tensor and now we just need first dimension as batched. I just updated the question. It seems like tf.equal not works for this case.

Comment: @Hypnoz: ha, you mean a vectorized version of the original question?

Comment: @Willen I think I may need a batch version of the answer.The input is [bastch_size, d,] bool tensor and output will be [batch_size, d, d] (in my case, d=9). I am also trying this,but it seems like much harder.

Comment: Actually I solve it, just add a new dimension. thank you. I also update my question.